# Reusing the model from R's forecast package

Tags: r, time-series, package

I have been told that, while using R's forecast package, one can reuse a model. That is, after the code `x <- c(1,2,3,4); mod <- ets(x); f <- forecast(mod,h=1)` one could have `append(x, 5)` and predict the next value without recalculating the model. How does one do that? (As I understand, using simple exponential smoothing one would only need to know alpha, right?)

Is it like `forecast(x, model=mod)`? If that is the case I have to say that I am using Java and calling the forecast code programmatically (for many time series), so I dont think I could keep the model object in the R environment all the time. Would there be an easy way to keep the model object in Java and load it in R environment when needed?

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions here:

A) Can the `forecast` package "grow" its datasets?  I can't speak in great detail to this package and you will have to look at its document. *However*, R models in general obey a structure of

> ```
> fit <- someModel(formula, data)
> estfit <- predict(fit, newdata=someDataFrame)
> ```

eg you supply updated data given a fit object.

B) Can I serialize a model back and forth to Java?  Yes, you can. [Rserve](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rserve) is one object, you can also try basic `serialize()` to (raw) character.  Or even just `save(fit, file="someFile.RData").

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question:

```
x <- 1:4
mod <- ets(x)
f1 <- forecast(mod, h=1)
x <- append(x, 5)
mod <- ets(x, model=mod) # Reuses old mod without re-estimating parameters.
f2 <- forecast(mod, h=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, Rob. I didn't find that in the forecast docs, eg `?append` only points to base, there is no hint in the `?ets` page either.  Maybe this could be added as a further example on the manual page?

Comment: Yes, it needs another example in the docs. There is already an analogous example for `?Arima`. However I'm reluctant to add more examples as R core already complains that the checks take too long for the `forecast` package. It would probably be better if I wrote a vignette to allow more examples.

Comment: Examples != tests (as it is tests that CRAN [rather than R Core] complains about), and you can always wrap `\dontrun{}` around it which still lets humans read it.